# Overloading specialized assignment operator based on typename

Tags: c++, qt, gcc

Okay, the title is a mouthful and hopefully specific enough, but I'm running into a C++ issue which I think is possible, I just can't seem to find the proper syntax.

I have a simple template-based property class:

```
template <typename T>
class Property
{
public:

  Property<T> &operator = (const T &src)
  {
    m_data = src;
    return *this;
  };

  operator const T& () const
  {
    return m_data;
  }

private:
  T m_data;
};
```

I need to assign values from a [QVariant](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html), which is also sort of a property but without templates. At the moment I am deferencering the values explicitly when assigning:

```
Property<QString> p1;
Property<int> p2;

p1 = var1.toString();
p2 = var2.toInt();
```

This works but it is tedious and I'm sure the compiler can do the work for me. So, I tried implementing specialized assignment operators based on the **typename of the Property**; in other words, if the template specialization is based on a QString use one function, if it is based on an int use another function, et cetera.

I tried things like:

```
Property<QString> &operator = (const QVariant &ref)
{
  m_data = ref.toString ();
  return *this;
};
```

or...

```
template <typename int> &Property<int>::operator = (const QVariant &ref)
{
  m_data = ref.toInt ();
  return *this;
};
```

or...

```
template<> Property<T> &Property<QString>::operator = (const QVariant &ref)
{
  m_data = ref.toString ();
  return *this;
}
```

..both inside and outside of the class declaration but to no avail. I get errors like "expected nested-name-specifiers", "two or more data types in declaration of parameters" and the like.

Any pointers to the correct syntax would be appreciated!

PS: the first declaration compiles witout error, but adding the same declaration for <int> makes it ambiguous since only the return type differs.

Compiler is GCC 4.8.2 with --stdc=c++11 enabled.

Comment: Try `Property &operator = (const T &src)` instead of `Property<T> &operator = (const T &src)`.

Comment: Not your main issue, but suggest `operator const T& () const&` (add ref-qualifier to the end) which will reduce the risk of creating a dangling reference with no warnings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original class definition is a bit wrong, as pointed out by Kirill Kobelev in your question's comments section.  Now, let's fix that and also add another `operator=`:

```
template <typename T>
class Property
{
public:
    Property & operator=( const T & src )
    {
        m_data = src;
        return *this;
    }

    // This one must be specialized
    Property & operator=( const QVariant & src );

    const T & operator() const
    {
        return m_data;
    }

private:
    T m_data;
};
```

The specialization is therefore quite simple.  Here's ones for `QString` and `int`:

```
template <>
Property<QString> &
Property<QString>::operator=( const QVariant & src )
{
    return operator=( src.toString() );
}

template <>
Property<int> &
Property<int>::operator=( const QVariant & src )
{
    return operator=( src.toInt() );
}
```

Now you are free to assign `QVariant` values directly to any `Property` which provides that specialization.  If you try to do it on a class that did not specialize then you will get an error.

Comment: Yep, that's it. I was pretty close at one point with the 'non-specialized' assignment operator but just couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer of paddy seems correct, it seems to me tedious to generalize it (implement a specialzed assignment operator to all the types that a `QVariant` can hold, in addition to QString and int).

An easier solution would be to specialize the assignment operator once for all, in a way that benefits from the built-in conversions that the `QVariant` provides:

```
Property& operator= (const QVariant& src)
{
    assert(src.canConvert<T>());
    m_data = src.value<T>();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't approve two answers, but this is pretty good as well. The assert is a nice extra!

Comment: This is actually a better answer.  You should accept that instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reputation to comment, nor the expertise to claim insight so please don't take this as an "answer".

But your question reminded me of a lesson on Cpp, Overloads and Functions over at http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions2/ .

Excerpt:

"In the example above, we used the function template sum twice. The first time with arguments of type int, and the second one with arguments of type double. The compiler has instantiated and then called each time the appropriate version of the function.

Therefore, result will be a variable of the same type as the parameters a and b, and as the type returned by the function.
In this specific case where the generic type T is used as a parameter for sum, the compiler is even able to deduce the data type automatically without having to explicitly specify it within angle brackets."

Apologies if I missed the point, but thought this may help.